# Sample inf file to create standard modem

Tags: serial-port, modem, inf

I started involving in creating a PPP connection between my embedded device(GSM modem) and my pc via USB.  My duty is to install a driver for my USB(Laptop End) to serial(RS232-Embedded Device end) embedded device (GSM Modem). I planned to use Usbser.sys file which creates a virtual COM port.

My doubt here is how to create a modem to communicate with Serial device.
I came to know that it can be done by using inf files.

Can somebody give me some sample inf files for this?

For converting COM port as Standard Modem Link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey review the MSDN Documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://www.osronline.com/ddkx/modem/modemref1_9wz6.htm

[imodem-readme.pdf](http://www.usr.com/support/imodem/imodem-files/imodem-readme.pdf)

Hope it may helps.